# Extend output of stream with groupingBy & summingInt in Java8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have an Topic:

```
@Entity
public class Topic {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private LocalDate date;
    private String name;
    private int points;
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

I'm getting list of topics in given date by spring data jpa method:

List topics = topicRepository.findByDateBetween(begin, end);
which on output has e.g:

```
Topic(id=1, date="2018-01-01", name="Java examples", User(...), 12)
Topic(id=2, date="2018-02-02", name="Java examples", User(...), 34)
Topic(id=3, date="2018-02-02", name="Java examples", User(...), 56)
Topic(id=4, date="2018-03-03", name="Java examples", User(...), 78)
Topic(id=5, date="2018-03-03", name="Java examples", User(...), 90)
```

What I try to achive is to filter my result output as (if date && User is the same add points)

```
Topic(id=1, date="2018-01-01", name="Java examples", User(...), 12)
Topic(id=2, date="2018-02-02", name="Java examples", User(...), 90)
Topic(id=4, date="2018-03-03", name="Java examples", User(...), 168)
```

My actual solution returns map with date as key and summed points as value, but I need to have more data given in output like User or name.

```
return topics.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Topic::getDate,
                Collectors.summingInt(Topic::getPoints)));
```

Maybe there is another way to instead of map return created dto for that case? e.g.

```
@Data
public class ResultDto {
    private LocalDate date;
    private String name;
    private int points;
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: Does the user need to be the same too? I mean, do you need to group by date and user, so that i.e. if for `2018-02-02` you have 2 users, `user 1` with 10 and 5 and `user 2` with 20 and 8, you would end up having two groups, `(2018-02-02, user 1)` with 15 and `(2018-02-02, user 2)` with 28?

Comment: Yeah, I gaved example what happens when User is the same. But you're right it would've be like you wrote.

Comment: OK, what about the name? Do you need to group by that one too? If not, it shouldn't be an attribute of `ResultDto` (or this dto should have a list of all the names that form that group).

Comment: Your right. It shouldn't. But we can assume, that we need that one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `User` implements `hashCode` and `equals` *consistently*, you could group to a map of date/user composite key and `ResultDto` values. To do this, you need two operations: one to map `to` and the other one to aggregate points for each group. (You can place these operations either in `ResultDto` or in a utility class, etc, here I'm assuming the first one is in a `Mapper` utility class and the 2nd one in `ResultDto`):

```
public final class Mapper {

    private Mapper() { }

    public static ResultDto fromTopic(Topic topic) {
        ResultDto result = new ResultDto();
        result.setDate(topic.getDate());
        result.setName(topic.getName());
        result.setPoints(topic.getPoints());
        result.setUser(topic.getUser());
        return result;
    }
}
```

In `ResultDto`:

```
public ResultDto merge(ResultDto another) {
    this.points += another.points;
    return this;
}
```

Note that I'm assigning the first `Topic.name` found in the `Mapper.fromTopic` mapping operation. I'm assuming  this is an inconsistency in your example, please take it into account if you use this approach in a real world scenario.

Now we can stream the topics and group by date/user:

```
Map<List<Object>, ResultDto> groups = topics.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        topic -> Arrays.asList(topic.getDate, topic.getUser()), // Java 9: List.of
        Mapper::fromTopic,
        ResultDto::merge));
```

This collects to a map whose key is a `List` with its first element being the date and the second, the user. These 2-element lists aren't very useful for later usage, here we're only using them to create a composite key and group topics by this key. The values of the map is a `ResultDto` instance that is initially created from the topic and then merged with other topics that belong to the same group (same date and user). In this `ResultDto.merge` operation the `points` are being summed.

The results you need are the values of the map:

```
Collection<ResultDto> results = groups.values(); // or new ArrayList<>(groups.values())
```

---

**EDIT:** Here's a slightly more succinct variant without streams:

```
Map<List<Object>, ResultDto> groups = new HashMap<>();

topics.forEach(topic -> groups.merge(
    List.of(topic.getDate(), topic.getUser()), // Java 8: Arrays.asList
    Mapper.fromTopic(topic),
    ResultDto::merge));

Collection<ResultDto> results = groups.values();
```

Comment: Thanks @Federico. Unfortunately I need to leave. I'll check that answer and accept asap (probably tomorrow morning). Once again thanks, and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to group by a subset of fields is to use a `TreeMap` with a custom `Comparator`.  Suppose you were to define

```
Comparator<Topic> byDateAndUser = Comparator.comparing(Topic::getDate)
            .thenComparing(t -> t.getUser().getUserId());

Map<Topic,...> map = new TreeMap<>(byDateAndUser);
```

The resulting map would use the supplied comparator instead of `equals` to determine equality and will thus treat all topics with the same date and user as the same.

This feature of `TreeMap` allows you to compute a Map of topic to the total points and it will only contain one entry for each combination of date/user:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.summingInt;

Comparator<Topic> byDateAndUser = Comparator.comparing(Topic::getDate)
            .thenComparing(t -> t.getUser().getUserId());

Map<Topic, Integer> pointTotals = topics.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(
                topic -> topic, 
                () -> new TreeMap<>(byDateAndUser), 
                summingInt(Topic::getPoints)
        ));
```